# How can I retrieve all commits from Bitbucket without merge commits?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-pipelines

I found this API for retrieve all commits:

https://bitbucket.mycompany.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/XXXXX/repos/wwwwww/commits/1afdd692dc99eae74c7280306ca97bcb237bbe5f

but the response includes merge commits. I want only original commits. Is there any way to exclude merge commits from the response?

Answer (score 2):

The Bitbucket Server API documentation [shows an optional `merges` parameter on this endpoint](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/bitbucket-server/5.1.0/bitbucket-rest.html#idm45588160411856):

> if present, controls how merge commits should be filtered. Can be either `exclude`, to exclude merge commits, `include`, to include both merge commits and non-merge commits or `only`, to only return merge commits.

I think something like

https://bitbucket.mycompany.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/XXXXX/repos/wwwwww/commits/?merges=exclude

should do the trick.